# C char name[8] to GoLang Name [8]byte

Tags: go, cgo

I've got a C function that fills a C struct:

```
typedef struct {
  char name[8];
}
```

I need to copy data into Go lang struct that has the same content:

```
type sData struct {
  Name [8]byte
}
```

The structure has parameters of multiple sizes: 4, 12, 32 so it would be nice to have a function that deals with more than just one size.

thanks

Comment: Do the structs need to have an equivalent memory layout, or can you use `Name: []byte`?

Comment: I am sorry, the struct is just a context.  I just need to convert data from C go data type of char[8] to go data type [8]byte, so I can discard c structure and work with go structure.

Comment: The size of char arrays is fixed as it represents some predefined data in EEPROM.  It would be nice to cary fixed size in GO structure.

Comment: It's up to you is you want to use an array, but Go already has a `copy` function to copy contiguous bytes.

Comment: My current solution is something like this:func charToBytes(dest []byte, src [8]C.char) {
 buf := C.GoBytes(src, C.int(len(dest)))
 copy(dest, buf)
},  but I have to write a new function for each size of array or put code inline.

Answer (score 1):

To make this a little more generic, you can decompose the C char array to a `*C.char`, then use `unsafe.Pointer` to cast it back to an array.

```
func charToBytes(dest []byte, src *C.char) {
    n := len(dest)
    copy(dest, (*(*[1024]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(src)))[:n:n])
}
```

Or maybe a little easier

```
func charToBytes(src *C.char, sz int) []byte {
    dest := make([]byte, sz)
    copy(dest, (*(*[1024]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(src)))[:sz:sz])
    return dest
}
```