# Generalized function to pass array of char from C to Go

Tags: go, cgo

I am trying to copy content of structure in Go

```
type test struct {
    a string
    b string
}
```

to C structure.

```
typedef struct {
    char a[10];
    char b[75];
}test_c;
```

My requirement does not allow me to change the structure of member types of both Go and C. I have written the following code, to copy Go structure to C structure, and i am able to copy them too.

> cmain.h

```
typedef struct {
    char a[10];
    char b[75];
}test_c;
void cmain(test_c* value);
```

> cmain.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cmain.h"
#include "_cgo_export.h"

void cmain(test_c *value) {
    printf("Inside C code\n");
    printf("C code structure Member:a=%s\n", value->a);
    printf("C code structure Member:b=%s\n", value->b);
}
```

> go_func.go

```
 package main
 import (
    /*
        #include "cmain.h"
    */
    "C"
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

type test struct {
    a string
    b string
}

func main() {

    var p_go test
    var p_c C.test_c
    p_go.a = "ABCDEFGHIJ"
    p_go.b = "QRSTUVXWYZ"
    fmt.Println(unsafe.Sizeof(p_c.a))
    StructMemberCopy(&p_c.a, p_go.a)
    fmt.Println("In GO code\n")
    fmt.Println("GO code structure Member:a=%s", p_go.a)
    fmt.Println("GO code structure Member:b=%s", p_go.b)

    fmt.Println("Call C function by passing GO structure\n")
    C.cmain((*C.test_c)(unsafe.Pointer(&p_c)))

}

func StructMemberCopy(dest *[10]C.char, src string) {
    for i, _ := range src {
        dest[i] = C.char(src[i])
        fmt.Printf("%d %c \n", i, src[i])
    }
}
```

Here am trying to write a generalized function to copy the content of Go Structure member to C Structure

```
func StructMemberCopy(dest *[10]C.char, src string) {
        for i, _ := range src {
            dest[i] = C.char(src[i])
            fmt.Printf("%d %c \n", i, src[i])
        }
    }
```

In the above code, when i call the function **StructMemberCopy(&p_c.a, p_go.a)**, with &p_c.a as argument the code compiles without any error, but when i send &p_c.b, it gives an error

```
cannot use &p_c.b (type *[75]C.char) as type *[10]C.char in argument to StructMemberCopy
```

Can anyone give some inputs as to how to write the generalized argument for **func StructMemberCopy**, as my C Structure array member size can vary. Mean it can become

```
typedef struct {
    char a[10];
    char b[75]; 
}test_c;

or typedef struct {
    char a[15];
    char b[40];
}test_c;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37446623/c-char-name8-to-golang-name-8byte

Comment: You can't range of a utf8 string and convert the runes to `C.char`. You need to do it by bytes.